# Trouble running cloned project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently formatted my system, cloned some project repositories on which I was working. I am using BitBucket.

I already placed required libraries in the directory which project classpath is pointing to before cloning repositories.

Also, My `Project A` is using `Project B`, which is already on eclipse Java build path also.
But, still I am getting `Red Info` icon on my `Project A`.

[image]

I checked my build paths for any error. But, there is no error.

[image]

[image]

When I run project, it shows dialog, "Errors exist in required project(s):".

If I proceed, following error shows on console.

[image]

I am stuck with this problem several hours now, please help.

Comment: What does the "Problems" window show?

Comment: Please explain, which window you are referring?

Comment: If you go to Window -> Show View -> Problems, you'll see a window that lists what is causing that red exclamation mark.

Comment: Archive for required library: 'path/to/lib/mchange-commons-java-0.2.6.2.jar' in project 'Project A' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file. Does it mean, its corrupted?

Comment: If you've just copied the projects, it's most likely that the path to it is just wrong. Try removing it and adding it again.

Comment: Yes, the jar was corrupted. Got it working now. Thanks for the problems window. I didn't knew about that.